# Redirecting domain to a particular folder on a different server

Tags: php, networking, redirect, cross-domain, web-hosting

I want to e-commerce platform like www.bigcommerce.com and www.buildabazaar.com. I have done with the backend coding. I have added a unique identification number for each customer to differentiate their products and choices. When a customer registers, a folder with his unique ID will be created in my domain, where all his images and styles will be saved. I have created like this.  But i am stuck when a customer buys a plan from me and he will change name servers , he should get his site to be displayed in his domain.

I don't know how these things works. Please someone suggest me how to go about it.

Comment: What web server software are you using? Do you want to truly redirect to your domain, or have the customers domain always visible in the address bar? This topic is very broad.

Comment: I am using Linux CentOS with Cpanel. I want my customer domain to be visible in the address bar not mine. I have built the platform using OpenCart. Please help me how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Apache's [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/) and define a rewrite rule per domain to map it to the correct folder.

Something like this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ /customer/private/folder/$1 [L]
```

I cannot say for sure it will work perfectly for your setup, so you should read up on mod_rewrite. It is very powerful and should handle your situation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I do not know anything about mod_rewrite. I will learn and try it out. So please till that time i will keep this post open. If i face any problem, will come back to you . Will  you please help me on this?

Comment: I will help if I can, but it would better to post new questions as you encounter them, or edit your original question here if you have new insight, to involve the entire Stack Overflow community instead.

Answer (score 1):

you must use `mod_rewrite` in order to do that (virtually), not by creating a real folder on the file system!

**Edit:** if you are using `Apache` as the web server.

Comment: Yes i am using Apache Web server with Linux CentOS. I do not know anything about mod_rewrite. Please can you guide me how to do it.